# What is the realm token good for?

Tags: ios, realm

When initialising a Realm notification, it's required to set a token:

```
// Observe Realm Notifications
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
self.token = [realm addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, RLMRealm * realm) {
    [weakSelf updateUI];
}];
```

I'm not 100% clear for what this is good for. Is is to keep a reference to self?

Answer (score 2):

I found  possible answer: the token is required to remove the notification from a view. With the notification there seem to be no reference to it.

Comment: Correct. The token returned by `addNotificationBlock` method is there so you can explicitly identify this block when you go to remove it. There's no reference to the token from within the notification block, so you'll need to keep ahold of it in a more permanent location, such as a class property.